# Stackoverflow's Related Questions

Tags: sql, algorithm, linq-to-sql

Just wondering how you would go about implementing something similar to stackoverflow'd related questions. Would you simply match the tags, match similar words in the titles, or words in the entire question?

Particular interested in a linqtosql method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Stackoverflow's [Podcast 32](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-32/) Jeff Atwood discusses how "related questions" feature works.  I would suggest listening to it for more detail but basically he says that it is a combination of comparing question tags, question title and the question text.

However, he takes all the question's text and removes the top 10,000 most common English words.  What is left are basically unique words related to that question with all the filler-english removed.

So while I don't have linq-to-sql information for you, hopefully this can get you on the right track.