# How algorithm of finding similar Q works?

Tags: javascript, ajax, stack-overflow

Maybe my question is not ask correctly but a this moment i don't know words how to say it better.
I like "Questions that may already have your answer" or SimilarQuestion feature in SO.

I want to try to create the same feature in my project.

How algorithm of finding similar question works?

in my opinion the good way to that is send ajax request while you typing text, and on server you create statement that find question in database by using like statement?

Is this right way?

Can you give me advice what better way to do this feature.

Thanks in advanced.

addition:
i find that my question duplicated with
[How to build a 'related questions' engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182671/how-to-build-a-related-questions-engine)

Answer (score 1):

Is not as trivial as it seems, indeed the referenced question gives you some pointers to it so try to start there.

Basically you're trying to reproduce the functionality of a search engine... you type a series of terms (your question) and the algorithm needs to find a set of documents that more closely relate to the terms you typed.

That being said you could try using something like apache lucene to try to implement fuzzy string searching in your app.